How to host NLP model as API?
I have trained a chatbot model and want to integrate it into an Android app. My goal is to enable chatbot functionality in the app by hosting the model as an API so users can interact with it. I'm looking for free solutions to host the model. Can you suggest some free hosting options and provide guidance on how to host the model as an API? So far, I have trained the model and saved it, but I'm not sure how to proceed with hosting and API integration.

I'm surprised such a thing exists. Do these help?

https://gathnex.medium.com/how-to-deploy-llm-for-free-of-cost-6e7947d9b64a
https://huggingface.co/spaces
https://www.reddit.com/r/LocalLLaMA/comments/1660abe/looking_for_testers_im_hosting_opensource_llms/

